# Is there a way to use MAPE (Mean Average Percentage Error) with cross_validate on sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I'm trying to use a regression model to train and predict a multi-output dataset (ie. predict multiple target columns).

There is no scorer for MAPE on this list from the sklearn documentation:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

I know that separately, you can calculate MAPE by using sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error. But is there a way to combine it with cross_validate()? I'm open to using cross_val_score or other cross-validation methods.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you found a solution already (as it has been long since you posted) but here is a solution I used:
I implemented my own MAPE function as described [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#the-scoring-parameter-defining-model-evaluation-rules) using the MAPE formula explained [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics).
in short here is my code (not quite clean but it does the work):

```
def my_custom_MAPE(clf, X_val, y_true,epsilon = 0.000001):
      y_pred = clf.predict(X_val)
      ii = 0
      for i in y_true:
          if (i < epsilon) & (i > -epsilon):
             y_true[ii] = epsilon
          else:
             y_true[ii] = y_true[ii]
          ii = ii+1
      
MAPE = (1/len(y_true))*np.sum(np.abs(y_true - y_pred)/y_true)
return MAPE
```

Then called it in the cross_validate as such

```
Scoring_type = {'R2':'r2','NegMSE':'neg_mean_squared_error', 'MAPE': my_custom_MAPE}
cv = KFold(n_splits=K, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
cv_results = cross_validate(Lin_model, X, y, cv=cv, scoring=Scoring_type)
```

I hope it helps